# Python : count the number of different values for a given attribute in a list of objects

Tags: python, list, count, attributes

I have a list of objects of class `C`. Each object has an attribute `attrib`. I want to know the number of different values `attrib` can take in the list.

This works, but it's 4 lines long. Is there a way to make it shorter? Nicer? More efficient?

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.attrib = val

# my list of objects.
# attrib is either 0, 1 or 2 (so we have 3 different values) for any object in the list
objects = [C(x % 3) for x in xrange(10)] 


# Calculation :
tmpList = [] # temporary list to perform calculation
for o in objects:
    if o.attrib not in tmpList :
        tmpList.append(o.attrib)
print len(tmpList) # print 3
```

Comment: `len(set(o.attrib for o in objects))`?

Comment: Might go under code-golf at PCG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one shorter version:

```
len(set([x.attrib for x in objects]))
```

Regarding time complexity, you can improve your original codes from O(n^2) to O(n) by changing `tmpList` to a Set. Because `if o.attrib not in tmpList:` is an O(n) operation.